# How to populate a flowpane with an inner class; JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to populate a FlowPane with some squares that inherit from Rectangle. When I run the code below, the window is blank. The FlowPane is not showing any of the Squares I try to add. Can anyone help me understand why?

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseButton;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;

public class NonoView extends Application{
    private Square[] sqs;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        sqs = new Square[5];
        for(int i = 0; i < sqs.length; i++){
            sqs[i] = new Square();
        }

        FlowPane root = new FlowPane();
        root.getChildren().addAll(sqs);
        Scene scene = new Scene (root, 200, 200);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    class Square extends Rectangle{
        Square(){
            Rectangle sq = new Rectangle(100, 100);
            sq.setFill(Color.WHITE);
            sq.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
            sq.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
                System.out.println(e.getButton().getClass());
                if(e.getButton().equals(MouseButton.PRIMARY)){
                    if(sq.getFill() == Color.WHITE){
                        sq.setFill(Color.BLUE);
                    }else {
                        sq.setFill(Color.WHITE);
                    }
                }

            });
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Application.launch(args);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Square` class does not really extend `Rectangle`, as you intend to: Within the constructor you are creating an instance of rectangle that is not part of the outside scope, it only exists within the constructor.

Rewrite the constructor like this and you should be fine:

```
class Square extends Rectangle{
        Square(){
           super(100, 100);
            setFill(Color.WHITE);
            setStroke(Color.BLACK);
            setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
                System.out.println(e.getButton().getClass());
                if(e.getButton().equals(MouseButton.PRIMARY)){
                    if(getFill() == Color.WHITE){
                        setFill(Color.BLUE);
                    }else {
                        setFill(Color.WHITE);
                    }
                }    
            });
        }
}
```

Comment: This makes perfect sense. Thank you!